# Related rates word problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A runner runs along a straight course at a speed of 4m/s. A camera is located on the ground 20m from the course (at the nearest point). At what rate is the camera rotating when the runner is 15m beyond the closest point to the course? Give your answer in radians.

[image: adad]

So I know this is a related rates problem. I'm just not sure what I need to relate. I found that tan(x)=15/20 so that x would be .6435. Where do I go from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the runner is going to the right along the $x$-axis. Let $C$ be the position of the camera, let $N$ be the nearest point on the course ($x$-axis) to the camera. Let $R$ be the position of the runner. Note that $R$ is *changing*, while $C$ and $N$ are fixed.

Then $\triangle CNR$ is right-angled at $N$. Let $\theta=\angle RCN$. Draw a labelled picture.

As the runner runs, $\theta$ changes, since the camera is tracking her.
We are asked how fast the camera is rotating. Thus we **want** $\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}$.

Let $x=NR$. Then $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ is how fast the runner is running. We **know** $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$.

In order to exploit our knowledge about $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ to find $\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}$, we will need a **relationship** between $x$ and $\theta$.

Since $CN=20$ we have 
$$\frac{x}{20}=\tan\theta.$$
**Differentiate.** We get 
$$\frac{1}{20}\frac{dx}{dt}=(\sec^2\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$
(we have used the Chain Rule for the calculation on the right-hand side).

Now use the fact that we know $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, and that when $x=15$ we can find $\sec^2\theta$, to finish. It is better not to bother with a calculator.

**Remark:** We could have written the relationship as $x=20\tan\theta$. Or else we could have written $\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{20}\right)$. Usually, once we have a nice simple-looking relationship, it is best to differentiate right away.

Comment: I really do not remember how to do this without a calculator! so you find theta by doing inverse tan of 15/20?

Comment: and we can just plug in 15 for x when looking for theta? and then plug that into sec^2(theta)?

Comment: When $\tan\theta=\frac{3}{4}$, we have $\cos\theta=\frac{4}{5}$ (draw a right triangle), so $\sec\theta=\frac{5}{4}$. Or else recall the trig identity $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$. Do it also your way,  with a calculator.

Comment: so I should get theta as being the same with all of those, correct?

Comment: oh I got it now! thank you for reminding me of the trig identity to help me get sec^2(theta). and then I was able to solve for d(theta)/dt. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome. The important thing, that I hope came through, is that in a related rates problem you need a *general* relationship between the thing you know about and the thing you want to find out about. Also, since many of the problems will have geometric/trigonometric content, recall of all the things you once knew will be necessary.